# How to Randomize Outputs in C++

Tags: c++, random

I am using Eclipse 4.6.3 on Mac OS Sierra.

So I have this code:

```
int main() 
{
    int GameState = ROOM1;
    int iRoomCounter[4] = {0,0,0}; // Used to determine if a room has been visited.
    string choice;
    char Name[25];
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl;
    cout << "Enter Your Name!" << endl;
    cin >> Name;
    cout << "Thank you " << Name << ". You will not be forgotten." << endl;

    while(GameState != DEATH)
    {
        switch(GameState)
        {
            case ROOM1:
            {
                if (iRoomCounter[0] == 0) 
                {
                    cout << "\n One day, " << Name << " was walking through a field and spotted a little Ejay." << endl;
                    cout << Name << " also spotted a cat. He wanted to pet both, but he could only pet one." << endl;
                    iRoomCounter[0] = 1;
                }
                cout << "\nWhich one will he pet?" << endl;
                cout << "Ejay" << endl;
                cout << "Cat" << endl;
                cout << "-> ";
                cin >> choice;

                if(choice == "Ejay" || choice == "ejay")
                {
                    cout << "He pet Ejay" << endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to randomize certain outputs, for example:
If I choose "Ejay", I would like it to either say "He pet Ejay" or "Ejay ran away." or "Ejay died." I am not sure how to do that. Will someone so kindly implement a way to do that in my code? Thank you in advance.

Thank you everyone!

Comment: ***I have two questions. If you answer only one question, that is fine. Yet I would like for someone to answer the other question.*** Normally StackOverflow is 1 question per question especially when the topic is totally different.

Comment: ***I have been struggling to figure out how to export my code into an application.*** I have no idea what you mean by this question. I mean your code looks like an application. Are you trying to create an installer for your application?

Comment: You may be over thinking it. You could use random numbers to help you choose between string A or string B and then use it as a response.

Comment: And if by application, you mean like a desktop application, you can simply compile it and create an executable. If you were referring to something with a GUI, Then that is a whole other beast.

Comment: @drescherjm , It's not an application right now. It's just code, in the Eclipse editor. I want to create an application (that is seperate from Eclipse) Ex: Undertale. That is an application. The code is in the Eclipse editor.

Comment: How do I create an executable?

Comment: Compile it with your compiler. I have never used eclipse so I can't tell you what menu option, keystroke or button does that.

Comment: Ok, so I compiled it, and its in the Eclipse console, but I want to create a desktop application.

Comment: You mean you want to create a GUI? That is a different problem.

Comment: Ok, so I've researched, and I basically mean that I need to create a desktop application that uses GUI, except there is no graphics in my program. It's just text.

Comment: Search for creating a c++ GUI application in OSX.

Comment: Alright. Thank you for your help. @drescherjm

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The way to do it is by using a random number generator. The simplest one, but not best, is `rand()`. Of course, there are better random number generators like `std::mt19937`, but I'll just keep this simple.

`rand()` will return a random integer, and you could use the modulo (`%`) operator to narrow it to a small range.

```
switch ( rand() % 3 )
{
    case 0:
        cout << "He pet Ejay" << endl;
        break;
    case 1:
        cout << "Ejay ran away." << endl;
        break;
    case 2:
        cout << "Ejay died." << endl;
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

For your second question, try to find a build or compile button on your IDE. I'm not too familiar with the interface of Eclipse, but it shouldn't be too hard to figure out how to compile your code.

Comment: Thank you very much @Xander Kyle Puckett , much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Answer 1: `int randNum = rand() % 3` creates a random number 0-2, you can then use this to number to select a string inside of an array. EX:

```
string randString[3] = {"hi","Hello","Sup"};
```

Answer 2: You need to simply compile your code to create an "application." A common way to compile code from terminal would be 'G++ filename.cc -o desiredname'

**EDIT: If you're trying to complete a GUI with your game, it is very challenging with c++. You might be better off researching other languages or frameworks to use.